# How to search Google.com via proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy, cgi

I am hoping to use Google.com through a proxy however every proxy I have tried results in an error message when I try to search.

Where can I find proxies that can search Google?

Comment: I think Google is very strict with people using Proxy's to do search on their site (other than normal HTTP proxy). It is a business that they run.

Answer (score 2):

I've seached fine using proxies.

I'm assuming you are creating an application that uses proxies, you can try the tor connector class on http://phpclasses.org that will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure they allow that, but you can load it via javascript on your own site using their API: http://code.google.com/apis/loader/